# Как сделать чтобы игрок через пробел вводил слова в строке, и потом одно из слов случайно выбиралось

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать чтобы игрок через пробел вводил слова в строке, и потом одно из слов случайно выбиралось??

Comment: Принимайте ввод, разбивайте с разделителем пробел. Что у вас не получается?

Comment: что писать в массиве? к примеру я создам массив int[ ] PlayerInput {что здесь писать, я же не знаю что игрок напишет здесь?}

Comment: Принимайте ввод

Comment: я могу узнать количество слов PlayerInput.Lenght

Comment: можете написать на языке c# что мне надо в массиве написать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```
// text - введённый текст (string)
var words = text.Split(); // делим по пробелам

if (words.Count > 0) // если слов больше нуля
{
    var randomWord = words.ElementAt(Random.Range(0, words.Count));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: мне не нужно удалить рандомное слово, мне нужно выбрать из списка слов, букв, цифр рандомное слово.

Comment: просто не удаляйте его, обновил код

Comment: а что означает переменная var и какие типы данных она может хранить

Comment: `var` - это просто синтаксический сахар, неявное указание типа. Настоящий тип зависит от присваемого выражения. `words` - `IEnumerable<string>`, `randomWord` - `string`

Comment: где изучить c#? я изучаю для юнити, хочу спокойно программировать

Comment: @Danya учите по метаниту, кодблог, симплкод

Comment: у меня вопрос, если при объявлении переменной не писать public или private, то переменная будет приватная? просто ее нет в инспекторе в юнити

Comment: да, по умолчанию поля и свойства - `private`, а классы, структуры и интерфейсы - `internal`